# SQLAlchemy, appending association objects with extra fields in association proxy relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many relationship between objects `User` and `Groups`. I have an association object called `Attends` which contains the extra field `role`. I want to reduce the verbosity of the association object relationship by using association proxy. Unfortunately, the documentation was not very clear on how to explicitly add the extra field `role` when I am appending a new user to a group.

Group class

```
class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    gid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    oid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organization.oid'), nullable=False)
    start_time= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    end_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, db.CheckConstraint('end_time > start_time'), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

    organization = db.relationship('Organization', back_populates='groups')

    #many-to-many db.relationship with users
    registered_users = association_proxy('user_groups', 'user')

    #one to many db.relationship with tags
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', back_populates='group')

    def add_user(self, user, role):
        if not self.has_user(user):
            self.registered_users.append(Attend(user, self, role)) <-- error 
        else:
            raise ValueError('user %s already exists', user)
```

Attend class

```
class Attend(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attend'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.uid'), primary_key=True)
    gid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.gid'), primary_key=True)
    user_role = db.Column(db.Enum(*GroupRoles.roles, name='role'))

    group = db.relationship('Group', 
        backref=db.backref('user_groups', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))

    user = db.relationship('User')

    def __init__(self, user, group, role):
        self.user = user
        self.group = group
        self.user_role = role
```

I receive the following error when executing `add_user` method:

```
        def _create(self, value):
>       return self.creator(value)
E       TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'group' and 'role'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_groups` should be a a list of `Attend` objects (i.e. a relationship to `Attend`), and `registered_users` should be a list of `User` objects. When you append to `registered_users`, you need to let the `association_proxy` know how to construct the corresponding `Attend` object in `user_groups` ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#creation-of-new-values)):

```
registered_users = association_proxy('user_groups', 'user',
                                     creator=lambda u: Attend(user=u, user_role='some_default_role'))
```

Note: SQLAlchemy doesn't know what `role` is, so you'll need to provide a default value. It *does* know what the group should be, by virtue of the `user_groups` relationship being on `Group`. If you want to be able to do `add_user(user, role)`, you can simply append directly to the relationship yourself:

```
def add_user(self, user, role):
    if not self.has_user(user):
        self.user_groups.append(Attend(user=user, user_role=role))
    else:
        raise ValueError('user %s already exists', user)
```

Note that this assumes you change your `Attend` class to use the default constructor.